# How should I interpret the output of the sparse_categorical_crossentropy function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, loss

As an input a have a float 1.0 or 0.0. When I try to predict with my model and the `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` loss I get something like: 
`[[0.4846592 0.5153408]]`.

How do I know what category it predicts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These numbers you see are the probability of each class for the given input sample. For example, `[[0.4846592 0.5153408]]` means that the given sample belongs to class 0 with probability of around 0.48 and it belongs to class 1 with probability of around 0.51. So you want to take the class with the highest probability and therefore you can use [`np.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) to find which index (i.e. 0 or 1) is the maximum one:

```
import numpy as np

pred_class = np.argmax(probs, axis=-1)
```

Further, this has nothing to do with the loss function of the model. These probabilities are given by the last layer in your model which is very likely that it uses `softmax` as the activation function to normalize the output as a probability distribution.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but how do you know which category name is 'class 0' referred to? Is there something like OHE.categories_ from the One Hot Encoder from sklearn?

Comment: @alan.elkin In case of using `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`, the category you have assigned to number 0 is actually class 0; the category you have assigned to number 1 is actually class 1; and so on. For example, if you use [LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) from sklearn, you can find out this mapping via `.classes_` attribute (see the documentation and examples).

Comment: @today does that mean if I'm using Sparse_categorical_crossentropy all the distributed probabilities of every class at the end sum up to 1?

Comment: @RyanWang If you use a "softmax" activation on the last layer, the sum of output values (i.e. probability values) would be equal to one.